# Add transform in where clause in hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am using UDF to add an hour to my given date and using it as filter condition in my hive query. But it is giving me below error.

```
FAILED: ParseException line 8:4 cannot recognize input near 'TRANSFORM' '('   '"201606161340"' in expression specification
```

My hive query is :

```
add file adddate.py;
select
dt,param2
from
my_table
where
dt>=TRANSFORM("201606161340") USING adddate.py and parm1="465";
```

My python Code is

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import sys
import string


def add_date(current_date):
    date_object = datetime.strptime(current_date, '%Y%m%d%H%M')
    # print(date_object)
    one_hour = date_object + timedelta(hours=1)
    return one_hour.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')


# addDate("201606152350")

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.readline()
    if not line:
        break
    line = string.strip(line, "\n ")
    print(add_date(line))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @GoBrewers14 can we add transform in the where clause since the hive documentation and tuts have given example where in the fields which we want to be displayed are transformed using external UDF not the fields on which we want to filter.